# JQuery UI Resizable prevents :focus on div inside a handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using `.resizable()` on a div that is inside a table. I also have the table header as a handle for the resizing. Everything works perfectly, but now I encountered a problem where I am trying to apply a `:focus` selector on some elements inside the table header, and it is NOT working when focusing the element. However, when removing the `.resizable()`, the `:focus` applies perfectly when clicking that same element. I've tried adding `tabindex`, `z-index`, and even using `.focus()` when clicking some random button just to see if the element is focusable, and it is not working, only when removing the `.resizable()`.

Is there any way to solve the issue? or is it an un/known bug with JQUI resizable?

Thank you!